# How do I toggle (hide/unhide) child elements of dynamically added components with v-for

Tags: vue.js

The following renders a header text and some child elements.
What I would like to accomplish is that the child elements toggle (hide/unhide) when the header is clicked. So in below example, when `Spanish01` is clicked, all its children should be hidden and when its clicked again the should reappear. 
I tried to find a similar case on the internet but could not find any. All help is welcome

[image]

```
  <div id="dashboard">
    <ul class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header"><h4>Cards</h4></li>
      <li v-for="card in cards" v-bind:key="card.id" class="collection-item">
        <div class="chip">{{card.group_name}}</div>
        <ul class="collection with-header">
          <li v-for="(value, index) in card.group" v-bind:key="index" class="collection-item">
            <ul>
              <li>
                front: {{value.front}}
              </li>
              <li>
                back: {{value.back}}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your cards data?

Comment: Several approaches are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58721567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put an extra variable on each of your cards. Then you can do something like this:

```
  <div id="dashboard">
    <ul class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header"><h4>Cards</h4></li>
      <li v-for="card in cards" v-bind:key="card.id" class="collection-item">
        <div class="chip" @click="card.shown = !card.shown>{{card.group_name}}</div>
        <ul class="collection with-header" v-show="card.shown">
          <li v-for="(value, index) in card.group" v-bind:key="index" class="collection-item">
            <ul>
              <li>
                front: {{value.front}}
              </li>
              <li>
                back: {{value.back}}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Obviously, you have to alter your variable `cards` so it contains the `shown` attribute by default. As an alternative, you can set up a different variable that contains the shown status and use some unique id to look up the value instead.

Comment: @Sumarai8 It hides the child elements on render but a clicking on the parents doesnt make them unhidden (no errors as well)

Comment: Likely because you didn't add the `shown` attribute to each `card`, which means it is not reactive. Since it is not reactive, it will not trigger a rerender.